# Как закрыть popup при клике снаружи его

Tags: javascript

Как можно сделать чтобы когда popup был открыт, то при клике на него он закрывался, а если кликать в нём то был открыт? (без использовая jQuery) c моим кодом когда я кликаю на элементы внутри окна то в консоли появляеться такая ошибка:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'contains' of null

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
   let actMenu = document.querySelector(".popup.active");
   if (e.target !== actMenu && !actMenu.contains(e.target)) {                    
     document.querySelector('.popup').classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="popup">
  <div class="popup__item">item 1</div>
  <div class="popup__item">item 2</div>
  <div class="popup__item">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Похоже у вас ошибка здесь `actMenu.classList.contains(e.target)` (пропущен classList). Код в примере не полный не могу проверить.

Comment: .contains я использую чтобы проверить есть ли dom елемент в модальном окне а не класс

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При клике снаружи окно закроется. Ошибка была в том, что когда класс `active` удален и вы пытаетесь получить элемент с этим классом то получаете `null`, а потом еще пытаетесь выполнить метод `contains` на этом `null`. Следовательно, после попытки получения элемента нужно проверить, существует ли он `if (actMenu &&...`.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let actMenu = document.querySelector(".popup.active");
  if (actMenu && e.target !== actMenu && !actMenu.contains(e.target)) {
    document.querySelector('.popup').classList.remove("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.popup {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="popup active">
  <div class="popup__item">item 1</div>
  <div class="popup__item">item 2</div>
  <div class="popup__item">item 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал вот так, на мой взгляд гораздо проще:

```
.popup{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.popup-frame{
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.popup__bg{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    margin: auto;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

<div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-frame"></div>
    <div class="popup__bg"></div>
</div>

document.querySelector('.popup__bg').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('закрываем попап');
});
```

В двух словах: разграничить попап и заднюю подложку в общем контейнере и повесить обработчик на подложку.